# Concatenation symbol between two sets

Tags: symbols

I am searching fo an appropriate symbol in latex for the concatenation between two sets

Thanks,

I want a symbol like this in the  following [image]image

Comment: I mean by concatenation that if A = \{ a_1, a_2, ..., a_t\} and  B = \{ b_1, b_2, ..., b_s\}, then 
 A concat B = \{ a_1, a_2, ..., a_t, b_1, b_2, ..., b_s\}

Comment: In school we used the `$\cup$` for a set union.

Comment: What do you mean with "concatenation of sets"? To you mean union? Do you know how to symbol you want looks like? If so, please draw it (e.g. on http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/classify/) and share the link / put an image online. If you don't know how the symbol you want looks like, then you should eventually rather ask on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can find pretty much every symbol for LaTeX here: [LaTeX_symbols.pdf](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf)

Comment: @OuBaï: You seem to have managed to make an image of the symbol. How did you create that image?

Comment: To voters for closing: ***where*** is the requested symbol in the documents referred to in the answers to the “duplicate” question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A great resource for this kind of question is the opaquely named [*Detexify*](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), at http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html. You sketch a shape with the mouse and it lists the TeX symbols that look like it, along with package and mode information. It did a great job with my very clumsy rendering of your symbol, finding as top matches the same symbols proposed by egreg and LaRiFaRi:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your symbol seems `\smallfrown` from `amssymb`, but raised up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\tieconcat}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\dotieconcat\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\dotieconcat}[2]{% auxiliary macro, don't use it directly
  \text{\raisebox{.8ex}{$\smallfrown$}}%
}

\begin{document}
$A\tieconcat B$

$A\sqcup B$
\end{document}
```

The symbol I prefer, though, is `\sqcup` that I showed at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use Lua- or XeLaTeX, you can just use the Unicode of this symbol which is [U+2040](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2040/index.htm). There will be quite a lot of [fonts on your system that support this symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%E2%81%80%20-%20CHARACTER%20TIE%20%28U%2B2040%29). You could choose one, load the package `fontspec` and do: `\newcommand*{\concat}{\fontspec{your-font-name}\mathbin{\text{\symbol{"2040}}}}`.

However, it would be easier to use the command `\tieconcat` which is part of the `unicode-math` package. The fonts XITS and Asana do provide that symbol. This could look like the following:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\[
A\tieconcat B
\]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\[
A\tieconcat B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to use PDFLaTeX, you will have to use `\frown` from `mathtools` or `MnSymbol` or for a narrower version `\smallfrown` from `amssymb`.

You can reproduce your symbol by raising them a bit up. Just adapt the `0.9ex` until you find it pleasing.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\upFrown}{\mathbin{\raisebox{0.9ex}{$\frown$}}}
\newcommand*{\upSmallFrown}{\mathbin{\raisebox{0.9ex}{$\smallfrown$}}}

\begin{document}
$A\upFrown B \upSmallFrown C$
\end{document}
```

[image]